# "Injure" vs. "damage"

Tags: differences, synonyms

- I have *injured* my ankle.
- I have *damaged* my ankle.

Could you tell me the difference?

How can I use injured/damaged correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, an *injury* is something that a person suffers, whereas *damage* is something that an inanimate object suffers.  So, "I fell and injured my ankle", while "the book fell off the table and damaged the box."

You can, however, refer to various body parts taking damage when they are the subject of the sentence, since body parts by themselves are not considered people:  "My ankle took some damage from the fall."  Or, "The box was damaged when I injured my ankle tripping over it."

(There's also a difference between an injury and a wound, namely that a wound is a type of injury that involves a breaking of the skin.  So a bruise such as a black eye is not a wound, but a cut or a scraped knee would be.

Further, being *wounded* generally involves having a wound or injury inflicted upon you by a third party, whereas being *injured* could be accidental or self-inflicted.)